# Linux issue with output file of size below 100M to text file

Tags: php, linux, directory

The following below is my code to list all the files in the folder to a text file, however I would like to only list file of below size 110mb, is it possible to achieve, how do I alter the code?

```
<?php

$folder_name = ".";
$d = opendir($folder_name);
while ($f = readdir($d)) {
    if (is_file($folder_name."/".$f))
        $writeLine .= $f . "\n";

}
closedir($d);


$textfile = "myFilesLIST.txt";
$f = fopen($textfile, "w");
fwrite($f, $writeLine);
fclose($f);


?>
```

I want list files that is 110MB and below to this file myFilesLIST.txt

Normally to display at screen it would be this command line

```
find . -size +110M
```

to display file of size 110 MB and above.

But what I want to achieve is to find file that is **less** than 110 MB and output to `myFilesLIST.txt` line by line per file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simple use length parameter.

Instead of

```
fwrite($f, $writeLine);
```

You can write

```
fwrite($f, $writeLine, 110 * 1024 * 1024 - 1);
```

And this way file should be always below 110 MB (maximum 109 MB 1024 kB 1024 B)

You can read more about length paramter in [PHP manual - fwrite - length](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

**EDIT - after explanation in comment**

You should change

```
if (is_file($folder_name."/".$f))
```

into

```
if (is_file($folder_name."/".$f) && filesize($folder_name."/".$f) < 110 * 1024 * 1024))
```

Comment: Sorry think we got the wrong idea here :) I mean how can I list files of 110mb and below and output them to myFileList.txt